# Can a past participle be used to indicate the future tense?

Tags: grammaire

The following is the first sentence of a description for a TV show:

> Au printemps 2020, le Biodôme rénové de fond en comble accueille ses quelque 4500 animaux pensionnaires.

and DeepL translator gives the following translation:

> In the spring of 2020, the Biodome will be renovated from top to bottom to welcome its 4,500 resident animals.

I know that "rénové" is a past participle. It's usage here *looks* like it's being used as an adjective (as in, for example, "le toast brûlé"). If I translate the sentence as if "rénové" is an adjective, I get:

> In the spring of 2020, the renovated-from-top-to-bottom Biodome welcomes its 4,500 resident animals.

Did DeepL make a mistake by translating "rénové" as "will be renovated"? If not, can someone explain how past participles can be used to indicate the future, and give me other examples?

Comment: What is the context of the excerpt?  When it was written, if the renovation hadn't happened yet, it could make sense.

Comment: @livresque: TV streaming services have a small paragraph that describe what a show is about, for you to read to decide if you want to watch the show or not. this excerpt is the first sentence of one of these descriptions. edit: i noticed that the first episode has this information: "Date de diffusion : 2020-11-17"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence uses a narrative present. It might occasionally be used to describe events taking place in the future but it is obviously not the case here so your translation is correct and DeepL got it wrong.

Here is an [example](http://gotomars.free.fr/jdr_lottes.html) of a past participle indicating a future event:

> *Nous sommes en 2300.
>
> La première base martienne fixe, **placée** sur l'équateur de la planète, remonte au 16 octobre 2060, grâce à une coopération entre la Confédération américaine (États-Unis, Canada, Mexique), l'URSS, l'Europe et le japon.*